# Attached databases in Honeycomb

Tags: android, sqlite, android-3.0-honeycomb

Has anyone ran into attached database issues with Honeycomb yet?  My application uses attached databases (working on 1.5 through 2.3) using the statements:

...

```
String newDb = "/data/data/com.stuff.app/databases/mydata.db";

db.execSQL("attach database ? as newDb", new String[] {newDb});

String[] columns = MY_COL_NAMES;

String orderBy = DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;

Cursor cursor = db.query("newDb.mydata", columns, null, null, null, null, orderBy);
```

...

This is working (1.5 through 2.3) regardless of the actual location of the sqlite database file (local or SD Card)...However, in Honeycomb, the db.query statement results in a "I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(  628): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: newDb.mydata ..."

I can manually attach the database from within sqlit3 by issuing the statement:

sqlite3>attach database '/data/data/com.stuff.app/databases/mydata.db' as newDb;

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. My main db is :memory: and the attached db is stored in external storage. Worked fine 1.5-2.3. Have you found any workarounds?

Comment: I posted something on the Android Developers Google Group here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/WVOeAoV7FAQ/discussion

Answer (score 2):

in Honeycomb, using bindargs for 'Attach' sql statement doesn't seem to work.

try this instead:
   db.execSQL("attach database '" + newDb + "' as newDb");

this should work.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I added a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15499